# Search across multiple MS Teams sites from one MS Teams site

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, content-search-web-part, microsoft-teams

When a Team is created it automatically creates a site collection in SharePoint for the Team created. I have 16 Teams created hence 16 site collections in SP Online. I am wondering if I can search across the Teams Sites on SharePoint from one site. 
So for example I have:

```
https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/test/
https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/test1/
https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/test2
```

I want to search content in all three sites from `'https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/test/'`

I have created a result source and made it default in https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/test

but when I test my query I don't get any result back. Here is my query:

```
https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/test1 OR https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/test2 OR https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/test3 OR https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/test4 {SearchBoxQuery}*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are using the OOB search “Search This Site”.

When you checking the path of “Search This Site”, you will find the path is like:

```
https://<technet>/sites/<site>/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u=https://<technet>/sites/<site>&k=<keyword>
```

It limits the search in “`u`” parameter value “`https://<technet>/sites/<site>`” scope.

To search multiple sites, you need a search center.

Information about search center:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/make-search-results-look-great

Or, send queries to `_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx` instead of using the results page settings as the parent in site or site collection level.

[image]

When searching with this setting, you will find the “`u=https://<technet>/sites/<site>`” query string will disappear., and then the it will search in the **default result source** of site or site collection level.

**If you are using Modern search**, it is different with the classic search.

[Differences between the classic and modern search experiences in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/differences-classic-modern-search)

By default, the modern search only searches the current site. Click “SharePoint”, as shown in the image below, to search everything in tenant.

[image]

Using the managed property to limit the results. For example, search "`path:<site1> OR path:<site2> <keyword>`"

Comment: Thank you for replying back @JoannaW_MSFT. I created a result source and made it default on the site collection. Then i went to _layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx page for that site collection and tried to search, nothing. I change the result source back to SharePoint default search and try to search for my item and Voila! Now I think my query in result source is not correct? Here is the query:

{?{searchTerms} -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople} https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/test OR https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/test1 OR https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/test2

Comment: btw I am trying to search directly from osssearchresults.aspx page with my search scope.